# Trying to hide the document until it's updated with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my `ready` handling:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).hide();

     $('.foo').each(function(elem, i) {
          $(elem).text('So long and thanks for all the fish');
     });     

     $(document).show();
}};
```

What I'm trying to do is hiding the document completely until everything is ready on my terms, but it seems that the `show()` function doesn't wait for the elements iteration.

By the way, I tried changing `show()` and `hide()` to `css('display', 'hide')` and `css('display', 'block')` but still, you can the text is changing in your eyes.

How do you make sure all your code ran before calling show()?

Comment: You should probably do something like `$("body").hide()`, I don't think you can set css properties on an entity like `document`.

Comment: it would be css('display', 'none'); not 'hide'

Comment: @Mash - it was a typo. you right

Comment: @ewein - You don't need a callback when there's no asynchronous code there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's suppose you fix this by hiding the body or a container element. That won't do the trick, and here's why:

What happens during the time after the document is (mostly) loaded but *before* you hide the document?

That's right, the document may get displayed during that time despite your best efforts.

So what you could do instead is use a CSS class that hides, say, the `body` without any JavaScript intervention. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        body.hide { display: none; }
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $('.foo').each(function( i, elem ) {
                $(elem).text( 'So long and thanks for all the fish' );
            });
            $('body').removeClass( 'hide' );
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="hide">
    <div class="foo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course this does mean that if JavaScript is disabled, your document won't be visible at all. What if you want to have a non-JavaScript fallback? In that case you could do it like this instead. We'll hide the `html` element instead of the `body` because that way we know the code will work in the `head` (the `body` element may not exist yet at this point), and only hide it if JavaScript is enabled:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        html.hide { display: none; }
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('html').addClass( 'hide' );
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $('.foo').each(function( i, elem ) {
                $(elem).text( 'So long and thanks for all the fish' );
            });
            $('html').removeClass( 'hide' );
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="foo">
        This content is displayed if JavaScript is disabled.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you have a non-JavaScript fallback, but the document will still be hidden immediately when JavaScript is enabled, because of the code that adds the `hide` class.

Also note that you had the parameters reversed in your `$().each()` callback. (Interestingly enough, the order you used makes much more sense and indeed is the order used by the newer native `.forEach()` function. The order in `$().each()` is really backwards - one of those things that seemed like a good idea at the time but really was just a mistake.)

Answer (score 3):

You can not `hide()` the `document`. Instead, try hiding the main container element on your page; or hiding the `body` e.g. `$('body').hide()` might work as well.

Just an aside: the `display` property should be `none`. `hide` is not a valid value.